# Как вернуть массив в Ajax?

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо вернуть массив в Ajax запрос. Причем не один массив, а два. Один масив будет выводится в одном месте, а другой массив в другом, но на той же странице.
Вот JS скрипт:

```
    $('.table_blur_search tr').on('click', function() {
    // удаляем у всех tr элементов таблицы класс active
    $('.table_blur_search tr').removeClass('active');
    // выбранной строке таблицы присваиваем класс active
    // в нашем случае в this лежит ссылка на обрабатываемый по клику элемент TR
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    // в id переменной будет лежать содержимое первого td элемента таблицы
    // дальше его можно куда-нибудь аяксом отправить
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'', // куда шлем запрос
        cache: false,
        data:{idclientspisok:id}, // отправляем $_POST['idclientspisok'] скрипту с содержимым переменной id
        success: function(res){
            // успешно выполнено
            $("#karta_client").hide().fadeIn(500).html(res);
        },
        error: function(res){
            // какая-то ошибка
            alert("Ошибка получения запроса javascript")
        }
    });
});
```

Теперь код на стороне сервера, то что должен вернуть:

```
 if(isset($_POST['idpersonspisok'])){
        $client_more = client_more($link); // вызоваем первый массив
        $client_more2 = client_more2($link); // вызоваем второй массив
```

}

Ну после этого их нужно вывести на странице:

```
$client_more[0]['lastName'].' '.$client_more[0]['firstName'].' '.$client_more[0]['patrName'] // выводим первый массив  

$client_more2[0]['lastName'].' '.$client_more2[0]['firstName'].' '.$client_more2[0]['patrName'] // выводим второй массив
```

Сейчас скрипт работает, но возвращает результат первого массива, через функцию echo. Хотелось бы просто возвращать два массива. Такое вообще возможно, или придется писать дополнительный скрипт? Я не силен js

Comment: Всё смешалось.. Массивы, строки.. Каков ожидаемый ответ сервера?

Comment: просто 2 раза послать POST для каждого пользователя..

Comment: Чтобы разделить ответ сервера на компоненты, он должен соответствовать некоторому формату. Обычно люди используют json. Вы же можете просто разделить компоненты маркером, например, переносом строки. Маркер внутри компонентов придётся исключить или заэкранировать.

Comment: @mostSpec у вас проблема получить дату из сервера?

Comment: Не совсем, проблема в том что мне нужно получить разные данные на основании одного и того же POST, просто чтобы не делать два одинаковых запроса я и хотел узнать как же получить два массива? И причем их нужно положить в разные блоки div. То есть я нажимаю кнопку, и мне тут же сверху дается данные о пациенте в виде текста, а ниже в конце страницы в виде таблицы,  данные о его обращениях. Не знаю как это реализовать. А хотелось бы, Просто один скрипт практичнее двух

Answer (score 1):

в `$.ajax` надо добавить параметр `dataType : "json"` тогда все, что возвращает сервер в переменную res будет восприниматься, как json массив.

`res.clientlist1[0].first_name` и так далее

Сервер должен выдавать только

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

, где `$data` - объект, например

```
$data = (object)array("clientlist1" => array(
array("firstname" => "vasya", "lastname" => "pupkin"),
array("firstname" => "papa", "lastname" => "rimskiy")
...);
```

Comment: Про `Content-type` заголовок не забудьте